# Cox-Snell Residuals: Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, cox-regression, model-checking

I am running a Cox model in R with 3 explanatory variables.

In the model checking, I try to compute the Cox-Snell residuals but I get this warning message:
"Warning message:
In data$death - residuals(death.model, type = "martingale") :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Since I have never come up to this warning before, I would appreciate any idea on how to handle the situation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider posting a small sample of the dataset and relevant code as example.

Comment: I would guess you have NAs in the `data$death` (if you had 6 values like: `c(10,1,24,NA,13,1)`). But then your model automatically will have dropped those NA values! So your residuals would now be a vector of 5 values! You can do `na.rm(data$death) -  residuals(death.model, type = "martingale")`, assuming that the missing values are in the variable `death` and not somewhere else in your model.